# How to use google-api-client for Google Cloud Logging

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-api-client, google-cloud-logging

I want to access to Google Cloud Platform Logging from a python script.

I have get to access to this logs from https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list --> Try this API

Now I want to get the same, but from a Python script. I saw that in step before, is created an authorization token automatically.

I am trying with this code sample, but then I don't know how to POST https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list using discovery:

```html
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file)
logging = googleapiclient.discovery.build('logging', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

Then I have tried with this code sample:

```html
import requests
payload = {
    "projectIds": [
        "my-proyect"
    ],
    "resourceNames": [],
    "filter": "resource.type=cloudiot_device",
    "orderBy": "timestamp desc",
    "pageSize": 1
}
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer AAAAAAA"}
r = requests.post("https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list", params=payload, headers=headers)
```

That code sample works correctly but where it puts AAAAAAA token I copy and paste the code that I saw in https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list but I don't know how to generate this token from a python script.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mikel. in Stack overflow it is expected that when asking a question you already have tried something and to include what you have tried in the question so the community can go from there. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxSwhRSHeDQ) is a nice video explaining this. and if you want to see what Stack overflow says on how to ask is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: For me your question is like you're looking for someone to do your work. "How can I get that? I don't understand very well how to get authorization tokens." is not a valid question. You should give a try and come back with any specific question with your implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is less easy to find because many of Google's Cloud (!) services now prefer Cloud Client libraries.

However...

```py
import google.auth

from googleapiclient import discovery

credentials, project = google.auth.default()

service = discovery.build("logging", "v2", credentials=credentials)
```

Auth: https://pypi.org/project/google-auth/

Now, this uses Google Application Default credentials and I recommend you create a service account, generate a key and grant the account the permission needed. You will then need to export `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` before running your code.

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
BILLING=[[YOUR-BILLING]]
ACCOUNT=[[YOUR-ACCOUNT]]

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# See: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#logging-roles
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/logging.viewer

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

python3 your-code.py
```

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin ! I get to extract data from Google Cloud Logging using Cloud Client library and service account authorization. Thank you! I am going to attach below the code sample which I am using. My doubt is how to limit the number of entries, because this code sample starts running and it does not stop.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks to the Google [Engineer](https://github.com/Daniel-Sanche), the first part of the solution is to disable the SDK's use of gRPC and force HTTP so that `page_size` is respected:

```py
client = logging.Client(_use_grpc=0)
```

Alternatively, you can `GOOGLE_CLOUD_DISABLE_GRPC="{{anything}}"`

And the second part of the solution is to only iterate over the first page of `page_size` results:

```py
iterator = logger.list_entries(
    order_by=DESCENDING,
    page_size=page_size,
)
print(type(iterator))

for entry in next(iterator.pages):
    timestamp = entry.timestamp.isoformat()
    print("{}".format(timestamp))
```

> **NOTE** forcing HTTP entails `logger.list_entries` returning an `HTTPIterator` instead of a (gRPC) `generator` hence the ability to use `next()` and the `pages` property.

> **NOTE** The 'trick' is to only enumerate the first page of n results. There may be multiple pages but we ignore subsequent ones.